If $AB = 0$, can the nullspace of $BA$ be trivial?
True or False: Suppose $A, B$ are two $n×n$ matrices, and $AB = 0$, then $N(BA)$, the nullspace of $BA$, is nontrivial.
I know that the nullspace of $AB$ is all vectors in $R^n$ so rank is $0$ and nullity is $n$. I also know that if false and $BA$ has a trivial nullspace, $BAw\neq0$ for all $w\neq0$ in $R^n$.

A $n \times n$ matrix has trivial nullspace if and only if it has nonzero determinant.
But in this case, $0=\det(AB)=\det(BA)$.

$AB=0$ means the column space of $B$ is a subspace of the null space of $A$.
If the null space of $A$ is trivial, then the column space of $B$ was trivial too (it being a subspace of $A$'s null space). So then $B=0$, and $BA=0$ with a (very) nontrivial null space.
If the null space of $A$ is non-trivial, then of course so is the null space of $BA$. Because whatever nontrivial vectors $A$ annihilates are annihilated by $BA$ too.
Either way, $BA$ has a nontrivial null space.

If $B$ is the trivial matrix, then every vector is in the nullspace of $BA$.
Otherwise, there is some nonzero vector of the form $Bv$. But the matrix $BA$ annihilates any vector of the form $Bv$, since the expression $BABv$ has an $AB$ in it.

+1; Or, in the otherwise case, there is some non-zero column of $B$, and it is in the nullspace of $BA$.
